# how can i get url of the application is connected to server?

Tags: applications, terminal, network

I want to grab server url of each application that is online with that.
Ex. twitter app -> http://twitter.com/...
Ex. Tweetdec app -> http://client.tweetdec.com/...
Ex. itunes app -> itms-apps://itunes.com/...

every app transfer, post and get data with special url of a host. i want a tools show their.

Comment: It's hard to completely understand what you're asking for but LittleSnitch may do what you need.

Comment: every app transfer, post and get data with special url of a host. i want a tools show their.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a proxy server such as [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com). Most proxy servers can be set to log every connection and the content passing through it.

To see open connections, including TCP connections, use the command line tool [lsof](https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html).

For detailed network debugging, get a packet trace. Apple's Q&A1176 walks through [how to obtain a packet trace on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1176/_index.html).